# Why is my month-old flag still active?

Tags: support, flags, flag-queue

I flagged a post as a duplicate over a moth ago, and it is still active:

> [image]

Why is that?

Before you say this is a duplicate of [Why does it take so long to review a flag suggested by a user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174259/why-does-it-take-so-long-to-review-a-flag-suggested-by-a-user), let me explain how the answers there are not satisfactory to answer this question.

One answer there says:

> it generally takes 24 hours to get a review.

It has not been 24 hours, or even 24 days. It has been over *40* days.

My only guess, based on both answers of that question, is that the "duplicate" section of the Flag Queue is full, like the Close Votes review.

Comment: I have a flag active from August, fwiw.

Comment: [link to question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19908867/1026459)

Comment: Because there's almost 100k question in the close votes queue... mods don't even see the flags any more (as is described in the linked question).

Comment: Voting to close as a dupe because of _"Finally, when we have a backlog of flags (almost always), we might tend to let some types of flags wait for community action, in lieu of spending moderator time on them... Moderators no longer see the "Close" flags in our queue; they will go to the Close review queue; so they remain open for a long time."_ in the answer to the linked question.

Comment: Ultimately a duplicate flag is the same as a close flag, which means it will be handled when the question closed or enough users click "Leave Open".  Until that happens, the flag will remain active.  I have one from June that I don't expect to see handled for a while.  Basically, if it isn't handled quickly, it will get lost in the long tail of the queue.

Comment: Is it possible to cancel a flag if I am tired of waiting for it to resolve and officially "don't care anymore"?

Comment: No @Tim. And you no longer caring doesn't make a flag unimportant or invalid. Just ignore it until it goes away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java is a highly active tag. As such, it can take a while for it to show up in the review queue (the close vote review queue in this case).

The queue favors recent questions, and it would seem that more Java questions enter the queue per day than leave it. Given that you do not have enough reputation to cast close votes yet, you will have to be content with having some flags which sit for a while if they are for question closures. Ideally this would have been a close vote and not a flag.

At your current pace, you will have enough rep soon :) Meta effect closed it now.

Comment: "just cast a regular close vote" I have ~750 rep on SO.

Comment: @RyanCarlson - And so you do. Well, soon you will have enough :D Until then, you might have some flags which sit for a while if they are for question closures.

Comment: `As such, it can take a while for it to show up in the review queue`... and I don't think the logic for ordering of close flags has been disclosed (if it has, please reference it as I'd love to see it), but the common belief is recent flags, regardless of the age of the question is put at the top.

Comment: @psubsee2003 - Corrected the statement regarding voting privileges. The logic is rather evident with regards to the queue though. It *heavily* weights newest close votes. **Heavily**. So the note that it will take "a while" is basically saying that if the question isn't immediately dealt with it will be buried and will not be reviewed until the entire top pile is reviewed. Really I am saying the same thing you indicate. That recent votes are at the top. And if your vote at the top is not fully actioned, it will take a while for it to come up again to be completed.